# How to get to know which anchor link being clicked using javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sorry I am new to JavaScript.

Says that *a.html* has two same anchor links (`<a href="b.html">b</a>`). The anchor links are uneditable but we could add JavaScript to the *a.html*.

Except for dynamic adding `onclick` event, any other ways could get to know which anchor link being clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery.
Add the click event to the anchors and show the id using an alert:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#anchor1").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
    });
$("#anchor2").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript on anchor tag call testClick like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function testClick(id) {
        alert(id);
    }
</script>

<a href="#" id="test" onclick="testclick(this.id);">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this one

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function testClick() {
    alert(this.id);
}
 </script>

  <a href="#" id="test" onclick="testclick();">Click</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to check is, as you suggested, through the click event.

Comment: Thank you. But if not using onclick event and just using pure javascript could be better for my situation.

Comment: Once the page is done loading, javascript is almost entirely event based.  This is the "correct" way to go about solving this problem.  Maybe you should give us more info about why you can't use events.